# Ethernet Shield web server - Can't find the index.htm file

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet-shield

i've just got the EthernetShield and watched a tutorial on how to host a html page with it but i can't find my html page on the SD card.

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include<Ethernet.h>
#include<SD.h>

byte mac[] = {0xA8, 0x61,0x0A, 0xAE, 0x3A, 0xC4 };

EthernetServer server(80);

File webPage;

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  server.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
  if(!SD.begin(4)){
    Serial.println("ERROR - SD card initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
    Serial.println("SUCCESS - SD card initialized.");
    if(!SD.exists("index.htm")){
      Serial.println("ERROR - Can't find index.htm file!");
    }
      Serial.println("SUCCESS - Found  index.htm file.");
} 

void loop() {
   EthernetClient client = server.available();
   if(client){
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while(client.connected()){
      if(client.available()){
        char c = client.read();
        if(c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank){
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close");
          client.println();

          webPage = SD.open("index.htm");
          if(webPage){
            while(webPage.available()){
              client.write(webPage.read());
            }
            webPage.close();
          }
          break;
        }
        if(c == '\n'){
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        }
        else if(c != '\r'){
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    delay(1);
    client.stop();
   }
}
```

[image]

When i save the HTML file i can't save it with the .htm format

[image]

Comment: What you served is not 369 bytes?

Comment: Are you just confused by the mention of "Microsoft Edge"?

Comment: @timemage no its not

Comment: There are reportedly 369 bytes in the file.  So what *does* the file contain if not what you wanted?

Comment: @timemage the file contains only the HTML code, u can see a screenshot of my error down below , in the Answer section.

Comment: The answers you are giving don't seem terribly connected to the questions asked and I'm don't know what more I can say or ask to help you except this: Your question *needs clarification*.  The additional information you're providing should be [edited into your question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/80469/edit).  There's not enough information here to make me think what you're seeing is unexpected.

Comment: @timemage I'm a beginner and I can't say that I understand very well what the problem is with the file size. I simply created an html file with a simple page and then uploaded the file to the SD card. When I load the code in arduino you can also see in the picture that it does not read my file.

Comment: Hi @antisocialkid and welcome to the Arduino Stack Exchange. It would be really helpful if you could add a screenshot (or the source text) of what is inside the `index.htm` file on the SD card. To do this, insert the SD card into a computer and open the `index.htm` file in a text editor like Notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is hiding the extension from you.

The file you showed is either `index.htm` or `index.html`. If it's the latter, you could change the windows setting to "show extensions for know filetypes", <strike>or change the sketch so it uses `index.html` instead of `index.htm. I'd go with the latter, as it's the easiest.</strike>

EDIT: the SD library doesn't seem to like file extension that are longer than 3 characters. So changing the code to use "index.html" doesn't work.

Comment: I've changed the sketch but is still not working [error](https://imgur.com/a/jcH9Je2)

Comment: Did you change `if(!SD.exists("index.htm")){` to `if(!SD.exists("index.html")){` as well?

Comment: yes, still not working

Comment: My guess is there something weird going on with that file. How did you create it? What do you see if you right-click the file, and select properties? Especially, what does it say after "type of file"; what file extension is between the braces?

Comment: Type of file: Microsoft Edge HTML Document (.html) and I created it in Visual Studio Code. (Save as > index (with HTML extension)

Comment: Weird. The file appears fine, but somehow, the SD library can't find it on the SD card.

Comment: also the  SDcard already has the format FAT32

Comment: Maybe try it with a `.txt` file. I'm running out of ideas here.

Comment: finally windows let me to change the extension file to `.htm` and now it works !

Comment: Ahh. I think it has to do with the [DOS 8.3 filename convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). It doesn't like file-extensions longer(/other) than 3.

Comment: @antisocialkid if the answer was useful to you, you should vote it up.  If it is *the* answer to your question, you should "accept" it.

Comment: Might be worth adding that it's probably available under its short name, which is likely `INDEX~1.HTM`